# Program not ending after 'if' executes events

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

it is supposed to end the `onclick` after pressing on the circle but it continues anyway.

```
from turtle import *
l=0
h=True 
circle(5)
def m(x,y):
    global l
    global h
    goto(x,y)
    if((x>=0 and x<=10) and (y>=0 and y<=10)):
        h=False
    goto(0,0)
def r():
    onscreenclick(m)
if h:
    ontimer(r(),1000)
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out what your code is supposed to do.  From the title, clicking on the dot should end the program.  From the text, clicking on the dot should turn off the `onscreenclick()` event handler but you'd have no visible way to verify that this had happened or not.

Assuming ending the program was the goal, here's how we might rework your program to do so:

```
from turtle import *

def m(x, y):

    if -5 <= x <= 5 and -5 <= y <= 5:
        bye()  # exit from mainloop()

hideturtle()
penup()

dot(10)  # use dot (diameter) instead of circle (radius) as it's centered

goto(100, 100)  # get the turtle away from center

onscreenclick(m)

mainloop()
```

However, if this behavior is your goal, we can simplify the code by making the turtle itself the dot and set the `onclick()` event on the turtle instead of the screen:

```
from turtle import *

def m(x, y):
    bye()  # exit from mainloop()

shape('circle')
shapesize(0.5)

onclick(m)

mainloop()
```

If I've completely missed the point of your question, please edit your question to clarify the behavior and goals of your program.